# What is the missing value?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, recreational-mathematics

IF,

- $3+5+6=15,18,72$
- $5+5+6=25,30,94$
- $5+6+7=30,35,85$
- $5+5+3=25,15,73$
- $9+4+7=36,63,?$

I've noticed that product of first and second number on LHS gives the first number on RHS,while the product of first and third numbers on LHS gives the second number on RHS. But,i'm failing in recognizing any pattern  by which i can get the missing value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern for the last one is: $15 + 18 - 6 = 27$ and then reverse it.

$25+30 -6=49$; $30+35-7 = 58$ and like that others follow!!